# Date interval using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, date

I want to select data's that are available in date `$checkin` and `$checkout` in my PHP code.
Imagine that I have 3 columns in my `tblreservation` `checkin` , `checkout` and `roomname`  and has 4 data's already.

```
DATA in `tblreservation`
checkin: 2018/06/14
checkout: 2018/06/21
roomname: room A

checkin: 2018/06/21
checkout: 2018/06/23
roomname: room B

checkin: 2018/06/24
checkout: 2018/06/27
roomname: room C
```

and here's the code in PHP

```
$checkin = "2018/06/25";
$checkout = "2018/06/26";
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * from tblreservation where checkin > '$checkin' AND checkout > '$checkout');

"SHOULD" OUTPUT: Room A and Room B
//because the room C is already reserved, then the room a and room b will select.
```

Here I am trying to analyze this situation, but i'm so confused on how to do this, please help me out of this problem.

Comment: well, $checkin is bigger/later than the checkin of RoomA, so that won't match.

Comment: you'd need to compare checkin with checkout and vice versa - but two options with an OR in the middle. But I'd do it the other way round: find the rooms that are blocked! (because the non-blocked could possibly not be in table at all)

Comment: `SELECT roomID from tblreservation where checkin<'$checkout' OR checkout<'$checkin'  OR (checkin<='$checkin' AND checkout>='$checkout')`  should give you the blocked rooms. Explanation: there are 3 scenarios when a room is blocked: The desired checkout is later than the reserved checkin, the desired checkin is before the reserved checkout, and the desired block is in the middle.

Comment: @jeff thankyou so much! but what do you mean by blocked?

Comment: having those you could do something like: `SELECT * from rooms where id NOT IN (SELECT roomID from tblreservation ...)` and you get all the available rooms.

Comment: blocked means that the room is already reserved (I supposed that's your scenario)

Comment: i'll try that tomorrow, I already turn off my laptop cause it's 5am here already. Thankyou so much! ill let you know if its work. Thankyou Godbless you :D

Comment: I'll write you an answer in the meantime. I'd be happy if you'd accept it if it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly you need to first find all the rooms that are already reserved for that timeframe and then find the rooms that are not in this list.
For the first one you have 3 scenarios:

- the desired checkout is later than the reserved checkin
  `checkin  <=  '$checkout' AND checkin >  '$checkin'`
- the desired checkin is before the reserved checkout
  `checkout >=  '$checkin' AND checkout <  '$checkout'`
- the desired block is in the middle
  `checkin <= '$checkin' AND checkout >= '$checkout'`

Putting that together gives us this statement, which gives us all the blocked/reserved rooms:

```
SELECT roomID from tblreservation where 
      (checkin  <=  '$checkout' AND checkin >  '$checkin') 
   OR (checkout >=  '$checkin' AND checkout <  '$checkout') 
   OR (checkin <= '$checkin' AND checkout >= '$checkout')
```

Now let's get all the rooms that are *not* in this list:

```
SELECT * from rooms where 
  id NOT IN (
      SELECT roomID from tblreservation where 
          (checkin  <=  '$checkout' AND checkin >  '$checkin') 
       OR (checkout >=  '$checkin' AND checkout <  '$checkout') 
       OR (checkin <= '$checkin' AND checkout >= '$checkout')
  )
```

All this is made of fantasy table/column-names and types that you need to adjust.
Also transfer that to a prepared statement.

[Here is a working sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92ad8d/25)

Comment: wait sir jeff, are you there?

Comment: the error is - `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)` i'm trying to fix this error, I already searched on stackoverflow on how to fix this error but i can't. Please help me out of this problem :( the error table is in the `NOT IN` thankyou!

Comment: I already fixed it! Thankyou so much sir jeff! May God bless you always!! Thankyouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Could you tell me the fix so that I can update the answer?

Comment: It's only typo sir @jeff, but it's work. But there's a problem.

`DATA in tblreservation
checkin: 2018/06/14
checkout: 2018/06/21
roomname: room A`

input_checkin: 2018/06/12
input_checkout: 2018/06/13

the problem is the room A is still not available. It's almost 3hrs I fixing it,

Comment: one question: Do you have datatype `datetime` for fields checkin/checkout?

Comment: I did some testing and updated my answer. There was indeed a mistake.

Comment: the datatype of the checkin and checkout, i'll check it tom, thankyou so much for the effort sir jeff. Thankyouuuu

Comment: thankyou so much sir jeff! You dont know how i'm happy right now!! Thankyouuuuuuuuuuuu!!